# How to set JDBC/JDBI connection for ClickHouse to be readonly

Tags: clickhouse

Tried following methods and none worked.

1. Calling setReadOnly() on connection or jdbi handle. [setReadonly](https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc/blob/f43febf82b42007d3a3f83ad266dd1a105d2f83a/clickhouse-jdbc/src/main/java/ru/yandex/clickhouse/ClickHouseConnectionImpl.java#L262) method is a no-op in jdbc client.
2. Executing "SET readonly = 1" before other queries using the same jdbi handle. BTW, "SET readonly=1" works as expected in clickhouse-cient cli.

I can use a user that only has readonly permissions but in my set up I need to execute write queries as well and don't want to maintain multiple user credentials. The need for setting readonly arises because the queries that are executed are from 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.clickhouse</groupId>
            <artifactId>clickhouse-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.2-patch3</version>
        </dependency>
```

```java
import com.clickhouse.client.ClickHouseRequest;
import com.clickhouse.jdbc.ClickHouseDataSource;
import com.clickhouse.jdbc.ClickHouseConnection;
import com.clickhouse.jdbc.ClickHouseStatement;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String chURL = "jdbc:clickhouse://127.0.0.1/default";

        ClickHouseDataSource dataSource = new ClickHouseDataSource(chURL);
        ClickHouseConnection connection = dataSource.getConnection();

        ClickHouseStatement stmt =  connection.createStatement();
        ClickHouseRequest<?> req = stmt.unwrap(ClickHouseRequest.class);
        req.set("readonly", 1);
        stmt.executeQuery("drop table if exists aaaa");

    }

}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Code: 164. 
DB::Exception: default: Cannot execute query in readonly mode. (READONLY) (version 22.1.3.7 (official build))
```